# Linear map between duals induced by linear maps between vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, transformation

Let $V, W$ be vector spaces over a field $F$ and let $\psi: V \to W$. Show that $\psi$ induces a linear map $\psi^{*}: W^{*} \to V^{*}$ naturally.

Although the question asks for a naturally induced linear map, it does not seem at all that easy to me. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

First, realize that the word 'natural' carries about as much meaning as the word 'obvious'. Don't let the word intimidate you.

Remember that $\psi^*:W^* \to V^*$, so if $w^* \in W^*$, then $\psi^*(w^*) \in V^*$.

Now select $v \in V$, and apply  $\psi^*(w^*) $, ie, make sense of $(\psi^*(w^*))(v)$, remembering that $\psi(v) \in W$.

The only way it 'fits' together is $w^*(\psi(v))$.

Rudin uses the suggestive notation $\langle v, \psi^*(w^*) \rangle$ for $(\psi^*(w^*))(v)$.

The above then reads $\langle v, \psi^*(w^*) \rangle = \langle \psi(v), w^* \rangle  $, which fits well with the Hilbert space notation.

Comment: Within this context, the word "natural" has a very precise and, imfho, important meaning: the sought isomorphism does *not* depend on any bases whatsoever. This says tons when we're used to almost any isomorphism we can think of depends on choosing bases...

Comment: What is natural about it? If something is deemed 'natural' in retrospect, it hardly warrants the moniker natural. I think the word choice can be bothersome/intimidating when one is learning?

Comment: Natural in the sense that you define on abstract objects without any reference to bases, and I can't see how it can be deemed defined "in retrospect"...

Comment: I guess using natural for the abstract hints at the root of the issue...

Comment: Why the downvote? After 2.5 years?

Comment: I've no idea and I've no idea either why was I pinned: I don't usually downvote answers and much less after two and a hlaf years.

Comment: What does pinned mean? I didn't think it was you :-). I'm just trying to make 100k by answering unchallenging questions :-).

Comment: It's when you do the @ thing and after it the name of a user. I thought that what happened here since this isn't my answer. It doesn't matter. Good luck with your efforts.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\forall\,\,f\in W^*\;\;,\;\;\psi^*(f)(v):=f(\psi(v))$$

Answer (score 2):

DonAntonio's hint is good. Here is perhaps a more intuitive explanation:

We start with a given $\psi$, which tells us a specific road going from $V$ to $W$.

The elements of $W^*$ comprise all the different routes from $W$ to $F$.

Now, your goal is to come up with a general rule (called $\psi^*$) for taking routes from $W$ to $F$ and turning them into routes from $V$ to $F$.

Do you see how to use $\psi$ to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more pictorial hint:

You have $V\overset{\psi}{\to} W$ and then given $W\overset{f}{\to} F$ you want to find 
$V\overset{f^{\prime}}{\to} F$

Here $F$ is the ground field.